# Crash "Invalid parameter not satisfying: bundleProxy != nil" [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] requestAuthorizationWithOptions..]

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, ios11

I cannot reproduce this on my side, but one of my users is getting a crash with the error below (on iOS 11).

```
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
Invalid parameter not satisfying: bundleProxy != nil
```

when the code snippet below is called:

```
[[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter]
  requestAuthorizationWithOptions:
    (UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | 
     UNAuthorizationOptionBadge |
     UNAuthorizationOptionSound)
  completionHandler:
    ^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
      if (granted) {
        [self getNotificationSettings];
      }
}];
```

I have no been able to reproduce it myself. And I've had no luck finding anything similar here or the web. Has anyone else run into this who can shed some light?

Comment: See my answer to this here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49559863/3900270