# App crashes when I'm getting UNUserNotificationCenter.current() from into a Swift Package

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing, unusernotificationcenter

This is the context:

I'm implementing Unit Tests into an internal Swift Package. A method into one Unit Test is trying to get Notification Center reference from `UNUserNotificationCenter.current()` and it is crashing returning this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
> 'bundleProxyForCurrentProcess is nil: mainBundle.bundleURL
> file:///Applications/Xcode%2014.3.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Agents/'.

I already made

**Possible solution 1:** Create a mock NotificationCenter from a protocol, which is used to extend UNUserNotificationCenter. It doesn't work, because when I want to access to method current() from variable userNotificationCenter, is not possible. Here the example.

```
import UserNotifications

protocol UserNotificationCenterProtocol {
    func requestAuthorization(options: UNAuthorizationOptions, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool, Error?) -> Void)
}

extension UNUserNotificationCenter: UserNotificationCenterProtocol {}

class NotificationCenterManager {
    private let userNotificationCenter: UserNotificationCenterProtocol

    init(userNotificationCenter: UserNotificationCenterProtocol = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()) {
        self.userNotificationCenter = userNotificationCenter
    }
}

class MockUserNotificationCenter: UserNotificationCenterProtocol {
    func requestAuthorization(options: UNAuthorizationOptions, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool, Error?) -> Void) {
        
    }
}
```

**Possible solution 2:** Implementing UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate's method into a class, then pass NotificationCenterDelegate to this class, but also is not possible:

```
class NotificationCenterMock: NSObject, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    // Some code
}

let notificationCenterMock = NotificationCenterMock()
let UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = notificationCenterMock
```

Anyone has a solution or more ideas? Also help to know if is not possible. My theory is that is not possible to get UNUserNotificationCenter.current() for two reasons:

1. It's a Unit Test target and there aren't Notification Center in that target
2. Is not possible to get Notification Center is if a Swift Package

That are theories but I haven't found documentation that help me to prove that.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: A comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49559863/3418066) suggests accessing the notification Center in your test setup so that things are initialised once your code needs it.

Comment: I am inclined to think that theory 1.) is correct. I believe what you have to do here is inject an instance of UNUserNotificationCenter inside your component where you need it and then in the real world you can pass .current() and in the test world you can create your mock UNUserNotificationCenter instance

Comment: I don't think you can create an instance of notification center since it has no public initialisers. You could try and create a mock object or create an app to host your package during testing.